# Connect to MySQL on remote server from inside python script (DB API)

Tags: ssh, python, mysql, port-forwarding

Very recently I have started to write python scripts that need to connect few databases on mySQL server. The problem is that when I work from office my script works fine but running a script from my home while on office VPN generates connection error.

I also noticed the mySQL client Squirrel also cannot connect from my home but works fine on Office computer. I think both are giving problem for the same reason.

Do I need to create a ssh tunnel and forward the port? If yes how do I do it? mySQL is installed on server I have ssh access.

Please help me on this

AK

Answer (score 1):

2 things i can think of, 1 beeing that the port is not open for your home, another would be that the user on the server was created for your office computer (user@office)

you can test the first with nc -vz *host*  *port* (default 3306)
second would be to query the mysql.user table and se how your user is defined

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
```